# Nagios - external monitoring host without real connect - how do?

Tags: linux, networking, nagios, server-settings

I've got a problem. I have a few external servers that need monitoring by Nagios, but they are in remote VPN networks. I must send monitoring data from vpn's host to Nagios who is working on public server, but I cant connect to any VPN.

My idea is sending the data form hosts to database on Nagios localhost server, and read it to monitoring services values.

My question is; how define hosts without real connection do so Nagios do not not spoke "Host is down" or something like this. For this moment I change IP value on 127.0.0.1 for each from external server - and host is UP and on nagios information website and I can add next services for each and read status from local database but is better solution for this ? I just want to add a host without an Ip address and running service in local environment - read from local database.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [passive checks](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/passivechecks.html).

To quote from the linked page:

> Passive checks are useful for monitoring services that are:
>
> - Asynchronous in nature and cannot be monitored effectively by polling their status on a regularly scheduled basis
> - Located behind a firewall and cannot be checked actively from the monitoring host

Passive checks basically do what you're asking:  they send the information to Nagios, even behind a firewall or on a network where Nagios can't track.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the response of Katherine :

> I just want to add a host without an Ip address and running service in
>   local environment - read from local database.

You can use `check_dummy` for the polling of your hosts. This command will always respond OK to Nagios. Like this, your host will be always `UP`.